# Trying to get a Sticky Footer working

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, sticky

I'm having trouble getting the sticky footer to work. Essentially, I want it to do exactly what this demo does

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

I have tried about a dozen tutorials trying to get this to work, and I just can't do it. Can someone help me out? Here is my site (It's running Wordpress 3.4.1)

http://hgsupport.x10.mx/support/

Thanks

Comment: Did any of these solutions work for you? If so, can you accept the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your CSS perhaps?

```
#footer
{position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Chrome Inspector on the example you linked (its shows you the DOM tree, CSS rules applying to an element, gives you a real JS console and a lot more tools and information), I saw he applied the following CSS to his footer div:

```
#footer{
    position: absolute; /* Allows you to position the element anywhere
                           you want without affecting other elements */
    bottom: 0;  /* Distance from bottom of element to bottom of page set to 0 */
    height: 60px; /* Footer is 60 pixels high, not too important */
    width: 100%;  /* width of footer is all the width of the parent element, which
                    is all available space here. */
}
```

If you want the footer to stay at the bottom of the *screen*, as opposed to the page, you have to replace `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`in the above code.

Viewing the source code (Ctrl-U in most browsers) and looking at the CSS would have done fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

That's the relevant CSS. You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYPK/

Edit: Example with lots of example text to show that it stays at the bottom of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZYPK/1/

Comment: Not what I want. If you add content and resize the window, it overlaps the content. In the example I have, the footer stops when it reaches the content

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this setup fits your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/yceaS/.

The key part is to have a wrapper `div` with your content and your footer in seperate `div` and then use `CSS` rules to fix the positioning

Comment: This didn't work; I just tried it. I have a footer, a wrapper for the footer, then another footer at the very bottom with its own wrapper (this was the only way I could get the footer to be 100% while keeping the vertical margins for the footers). I also don't have an HTML file, so I added the HTML code to the page.php file (Don't know if that is right). I left what I did in my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and this did it for me!

Here is the CSS:

```
html{
   height: 100%;
}
body{
   height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -100px auto;
   /*The -100px mentioned above needs to be the exact height of the footer.*/
}
.footer{
   height: 100px;
   clear: both;
   position: relative;
}
.nudge{
   height: 100px;
   clear: both;
}
```

The HTML is formatted as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      Your main content goes in here
      <div class="nudge"></div>
      <!--The nudge div should remain empty and makes space for the negative margin assigned above.-->
    </div><!--END class="wrapper" -->
    <footer>
      Your footer content goes in here
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The nudge was what was missing from all the other solutions on the web and in the other answers.

Source: http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2009/01/css-sticky-footer/